# Can I access component/placeholder hierarchy from a `getPlaceholderRenderings` processor?

Tags: presentation, placeholders

Our solution is using dynamic placeholders. We have a requirement to restrict what renderings can be inserted in the page content (under the `content` placeholder) and in the sidebar (placeholder `right-sidebar`). The restriction should be applied on all nesting levels.

What I'd like to do is make a custom `getPlaceholderRenderings` processor which would return allowed renderings of the `content` placeholder for every placeholder rendered *inside* `content`. The challenge is in finding out the part of the page the placeholder is being rendered in.

Comment: Have you tried to access `PlaceholderKey` property (from `GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs`)? I guess this returns placeholder path, so you can check whether you currently processed placeholder is nested under `content`/`right-sidebar`

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak Thank you, this has worked well for me. Feel free to write up an answer and I'll mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline will be executed for each placeholder on the page so you will be able to process each nested placeholder and a make decision about available renderings.

Your `Process` method accepts `GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs` type as an argument.

`GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs` type contains:

- `PlaceholderRenderings` - list of Rendering items.
- `PlaceholderKey` - current placeholder path

`PlaceholderKey` returns a placeholder path (not single placeholder key), so you can check whether your currently processed placeholder is nested under `content`/`right-sidebar`.